# Symfony InvalidArgumentException when running app/console

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, assetic

I have been developing a website using Symfony.  Everything was good until earlier today I was adding some Fixtures using the DoctrineFixturesBundle and ran the "app/console" command.  I received the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
 Symfony\\Bundle\\AsseticBundle\\EventListener\\RequestListener
 is not a valid class name for the "assetic.request_listener" service.
```

I tried undoing the changes I made to the fixtures to find my mistake and it didn't change.  In my infinite wisdom, I decided to try updating my vendors by running "composer update" and it didn't work.

Also, when I run my site in a browser, I get the same error.

I don't know what's going on.  Someone please help, any help appreciated.

Comment: cleared cache? using apc/zend opcode -> clear that aswell :)

Comment: Part of the problem is that I can't do anything with console.  I cleared it manually thought.  It didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to let you all know how I fixed it.  It's not the most elegant solution but it worked.  I downloaded a new company of Symfony, copied over all my bundles, my whole config directory,my composer.json, and my AppKernel.php.  It got rid of all my errors, even some cache issues I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

For those who stop by :)

In most cases problem is with class name which has leading \ in front of class name. More info [more info](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5209#issuecomment-7577043)

Comment: In my case, I had a trailing ';' at the end of my class name

Comment: A leading \ was exactly my problem!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this error is always related to one thing and that's the name of the class is wrong. Either you are specifying the path the class incorrectly, or you spelled the name wrong.

For instance, I got stumped on this one because I accidentally add .php to the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Reformat on .xml files gave me same issue. Exactly, reformat the files in a directory instead of a single file, working with PhpStorm.

@abarisone:
Problem was in a services.xml file. PhpStorm "reformat" transform (example):

```
    <parameter key="xxx">Petrus\xx\xx\XHRCoreExceptionListener</parameter>
```

to:

```
    <parameter key="xxx">
        Petrus\xx\xx\XHRCoreExceptionListener
    </parameter>
```

Was hard to find and easy to correct, manually with help of "Local history" Phpstorm's feature.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?