# Symfony InvalidArgumentException when runing app/console

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning symfony2,and when running app/console,the error occure

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  The service "sensio_distribution.security_checker.command" tagged "console.
  command" must be a subclass of "Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command".
```

Someone please help, any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you replace the `sensio_distribution.security_checker.command` service with your own implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution but it worked.Downloaded a new company of Symfony,copied over all your old files;
[refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330422/symfony-invalidargumentexception-when-running-app-console)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're supposed to type `start` instead of `run` **[version 3.0]:**

```
 php bin/console server:start
```

Refer [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html).

**[version 2.8 and earlier]:**

```
 php app/console server:start
```

**EDIT**: Since you've contacted me in a weird way of editing my post with the new error, let me try to fix that one as well. It seemed to me that you haven't installed symfony at all since it doesn't recognize the command you've typed. Follow [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) as to how to properly configure symfony.

Comment: It's not work,and some erro occure: "Could not open input file: bin/console"

Comment: you are kind,the first time is always hard,let me see.

Comment: @liam If you are using 2.8, you need to use `php app/console server:start` instead (as [per manual](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html))

Comment: @liam did you fix it?

Comment: @Vucko,I downloaded a new company of Symfony, copied over all my bundles, my whole config directory,my composer.json, and my AppKernel.php,then it work~! It's not a smart way;  Thank you,guy~!

Comment: Well, it is the only way since you probably failed to install it the first time. Good for you, you're welcome.